# Browser is showing the output But Postman is not

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am displaying some number and it is automatically changing after 5 seconds. When I am opening it in Browser, its showing me the output. But the problem is, when I am opening the same url in Postman, it is not showing me anything.

Here is my code,

```
<span id="my_number"></span>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadRandom() {
         var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
          $('#my_number').text(number);
    }

    loadRandom(); // for initial display

    setInterval(function() {
         loadRandom(); // it excutes every 5sec
      },5000);
</script>

My url : http://localhost/test/getnumber
```

Where the code is wrong, please help me out.

[image]

Comment: I have edited my question,

Comment: Maybe you are using using wrong content-type when sending the GET request from Postman

Comment: I have added the image above, please check whats wrong

Comment: You can see the HTML in the response at the bottom of the screenshot. What’s the problem?

Comment: Postman won't run the JavaScript (maybe it would in preview mode, if that's what the problem is) but why would you need postman to run the JavaScript since you already have a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Click the preview button. You are just vieweing its HTML code

[image]

Comment: because postman does not run javascript. As there is no other content, you are seeing a blank output. Here is a link from postman's community https://community.postman.com/t/is-theres-possibility-to-run-js-in-a-request/8161/2